# Remove HTML Tags After a Specific Tag

Tags: .net, csquery

I am trying to remove some HTML tags from an HTML string.

My HTML looks like following:

```
<p>Dont want to remove this tag</p>    
<p class="MsoNormal"><font face="Times New Roman">Remove all Tag after this tag except style</font><p>some more text here</p><a>some more text here</a></p>
<p>dsa</p>
<p>dsa</p>
<p>dsa</p>
<p>dsa</p>
<p></p>
.... more tags here but all are <p> with some nested p and span
<p>dsa</p>
<p></p>
<p>dsa</p>
<p>Last tag to be removed</p>
<style>some style</style>
```

What I have tried is

```
var element = dom["p:Contains(\"Remove all Tag after this tag\")"];
if (element!=null)
{
   var newHTML = dom[element.Selector.ToString()].Remove();
}
```

but it is not working. It gives me the deleted node. I want the remaining html after removig the nodes. CSQuery or even a .NET string replacement solution will also work for me.

Expected result is

```
 <p>Dont want to remove this tag</p>
 <style>some style</style>
```

Comment: I recommend use HTML Agility Pack

Comment: how would that fix it?

Comment: can you specify what tag you need? 
you can find any element whit xpath in html Agility Pack

Comment: I can also find with CSQuery but problem is how to delete them. Example HTML and expected output is mentioned in the question.

Comment: any help please?